# Várias páginas com um id diferente

Tags: php

Tenho varias páginas PHP , com nomes diferentes claro. Queria era que ter algo deste género `home.php?id=0`, na página a seguir tem o nome de `cliente.php` queria que quando tenho o `home` aberto ao clicar no `cliente.php` no menu cliente abrisse o `cliente.php` só que no URL aparece-se `home.php?id=0`.

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Isso se trata de url amigáveis, você deveria alterar o .htacess ou o webconfig (dependendo qual servidor utiliza). Não prefere exibir so ó nome? tipo: www.pagina.cliente

Comment: queria algo como www.pagina.com/home.php?id=0  www.pagina.com/home.php?id=1 etc ou www.pagina.com/home /www.pagina.com/cliente

Comment: Bom dia @Bia não precisa de mod_rewrite só para isto, basta cliente.php estar em um `include`, não que será mais fácil criar assim, mas no caso do mod_rewrite muitas vezes terá que reescrever a estrutura :/

Comment: estou a usar o iss express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que percebi quer que ao clicar no menu cliente que vá para o script `cliete.php` mas que a URL seja `home.php?id=1`.

Pode para isso colocar a URL do menu cliente como `home.php?id=1`:

```
<a href='home.php?id=1'>Cliente</a>
```

E no script `home.php` fazer assim:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
if($id == 1)
   require('cliente.php');
```

Comment: nao essa url é home.php -> home.php?id=0  , cliente.php -> home.php?id=1 é isto que quero  tenho um file com os menus

Comment: @user2964140 vê a minha edição. Se não for isso tens de explicar melhor.

Comment: sim é isso amigo funcionou obrigado ;)

Answer (score 2):

Altere seu webconfig para esconder a extensão .php, observe quando digo esconder é apenas ocultar o .php:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="exemplo 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: tentei fazer isso mas nao funcionou

Comment: @user2964140 deixe-me ver seu webconfig

Comment: @user2964140 você tentou acessar www.pagina.com/cliente qual erro deu?

Comment: nao aparece a pagina

Comment: 404 - Ficheiro ou directório não encontrado.
A página que procura poderá ter sido removida, o nome poderá ter sido alterado ou poderá estar temporariamente indisponível.

Answer (score -1):

É só colocar o link junto com a variável `GET`
exemplo:

```
<a href='home.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'>Tal cliente</a>
```

e fazer uma validação pra trazer o cliente.php